# How do I paginate a NodeSet?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, xml-parsing, nokogiri, will-paginate

I would like to paginate my results from my XML parse. At the moment I get:

```
undefined method `paginate' for #<Nokogiri::XML::NodeSet:0x0000000374e408>
```

This is how I am implementing the pagination:

```
//Controller
require 'will_paginate/array'
def index
  @mycontacts = getcontact.paginate(:page => params[:page], :per_page => 30)
end
```

I guess that the returned NodeSet is not an array, but in what format is the NodeSet and can I use `will_paginate` on this or do I have to do something else to paginate my results?

Answer (score 0):

This may help someone else so am answering myself, Needed to turn the nodeset into an array so that i could use will_paginate

```
def index
  @mycontacts = getcontact.to_a.paginate(:page => params[:page], :per_page => 30)
end
```